# inserting into a sql table, values input to some text boxes,combo boxes and a datetimepicker by csharp

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm really new to c sharp and trying to learn the things by myself. I need to insert some data to the table of Findings in SQL database which will be input by a user, to some text boxes, combo boxes and to a datetimepicker. My method is as follows.

```
 private void SaveAsNewFinding_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("You are About to Save Your Finding \nAre You Sure You Want to Do this?", "Save Findings", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
      if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
      {


          Edit.Enabled = true;
          Back.Enabled = true;
          Next.Enabled = true;
          Save.Visible = false;
          Cancel.Visible = false;
          Find_FC_ID();

          String FByTitle ="INSERT INTO dbo.Findings 
                            (Findings.Findings_Title, Findings.Findings_Description,Findings.Findings_Rating,Findings.Findings_Implication,Findings.Findings_Recomendation,Findings.Findings_ManagementComment,Findings.Findings_ManagerResponsible,Findings.Findings_CompletionDate,Findings.Findings_Status)
                            VALUES (@FindingsTitle,@FindingsDescription,@FindingsRating,@FindingsImplication,@FindingsRecomendation,@FindingsManagementComment,@FindingsManagerResponsible,@FindingsCompletionDate,@FindingsStatus)";






          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(FByTitle, con.main_connect());
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindingsTitle",Findings_Title_TextBox.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindingsDescription",Findings_Description_TextBox.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindingsRating",Findings_Rating_ComboBox.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindingsImplication",Findings_Implication_TextBox.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindingsRecommendation",Findings_Recommendation_TextBox.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindingsManagementComment",Findings_Comment_TextBox.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindingsManagerResponsible",Findings_Responsibleperson_TextBox.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindingsCompletionDate",(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text)).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FindingsStatus",Findings_Status_ComboBox.Text);



          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 




          //  reader.Read();

          //reader.Close();
          Findings_Title_TextBox.ReadOnly = true;
          Findings_Description_TextBox.ReadOnly = true;
          //Findings_Rating_ComboBo
          Findings_Implication_TextBox.ReadOnly = true;
          Findings_Recommendation_TextBox.ReadOnly = true;
          Findings_Comment_TextBox.ReadOnly = true;
          Findings_Responsibleperson_TextBox.ReadOnly = true;
          dateTimePicker1.Enabled = false;
          Findings_Status_ComboBox.Enabled = false;
          Findings_Rating_ComboBox.Enabled = false;
          treeView1.Visible = false;


      }

      else if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
      {
          Edit.Enabled = true;
          Back.Enabled = true;
          Next.Enabled = true;
          Save.Visible = false;
          Cancel.Visible = false;

          Display(F_ID);

      }

      else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
      {


      }

  }
```

This method gives me the below errors and I do not have any idea how to fix them.

```
Error   1   Newline in constant Line-484(line which contains INSERT INTO dbo.Findings)
Error   2   Newline in constant Line-486(Line which contain the VALUES of the query)
Error   3   ; expected Line-485 (Line which contain the columns of the table)
Error   4   ; expected Line-486 Line-486(Line which contain the VALUES of the query)
Error   5   ; expected Line-486 Line-486(Line which contain the VALUES of the query)
```

According to the book which I'm following to learn theories above suggestions for the errors will not be applicable. 
Appreciate your help to sort out the issues. Please be kind enough to clarify simply since I'm new to the language.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There is two different types of string in C#. You may read bout it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

To solve problem in your code change type of your string

```
  string FByTitle =@"INSERT INTO dbo.Findings 
                            (Findings.Findings_Title, Findings.Findings_Description,Findings.Findings_Rating,Findings.Findings_Implication,Findings.Findings_Recomendation,Findings.Findings_ManagementComment,Findings.Findings_ManagerResponsible,Findings.Findings_CompletionDate,Findings.Findings_Status)
                            VALUES (@FindingsTitle,@FindingsDescription,@FindingsRating,@FindingsImplication,@FindingsRecomendation,@FindingsManagementComment,@FindingsManagerResponsible,@FindingsCompletionDate,@FindingsStatus)";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.Once I used the coding as above it removed the errors.But it gave me another error which related to a column in my table. I will look into that. But honestly, I did not understand the theory behind it. I followed your link and it also did not help me that far. Appreciate if you can suggest a descriptive link which suit for a beginner to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert line breaks like it looks you did in the `String FByTitle`string.

If you want to avoid long lines, like you should you must write it like this:

```
String FByTitle ="INSERT INTO dbo.Findings " + 
                "(Findings.Findings_Title, Findings.Findings_Description,Findings.Findings_Rating," + 
                "Findings.Findings_Implication,Findings.Findings_Recomendation,Findings.Findings_ManagementComment," + 
                "Findings.Findings_ManagerResponsible,Findings.Findings_CompletionDate,Findings.Findings_Status) " + 
                " VALUES (@FindingsTitle,@FindingsDescription,@FindingsRating,@FindingsImplication," + 
                "@FindingsRecomendation,@FindingsManagementComment,@FindingsManagerResponsible,@FindingsCompletionDate,@FindingsStatus)";
```

Or even shorter. Each segment is on a line of its own and you concatenate with a '+' sign.

This isn't VB ;-)